# Rounding off percentages in plotly pie charts

Tags: r

```
label=c("<25%","25 - 50%",">75%")
values=c(4,2,3)
df=data.frame(label,values)
plot_ly(df, labels = ~label, values = ~values,text=values,textposition="auto", type = 'pie') %>%layout(title = 'Percentage Effort time',showlegend=T,
     xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
     yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
```

When I run this code, I get a pie chart with percentages and the numbers. How can I obtain percentages that are rounded off to whole numbers instead of decimal points?

[image: Pie chart]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `textinfo='text'` to hide the percent values and provide a custom formatted label with `text`:

```
    text = ~paste(round((values / sum(values))*100, 0)),
    textinfo='text',
```

Complete example:

```
library(magrittr)
library(plotly)

label=c("<25%","25 - 50%",">75%")
values=c(4,2,3)
df=data.frame(label,values)
plot_ly(df, 
        labels = ~label, 
        values = ~values,
        text = ~paste(round((values / sum(values))*100, 0)),
        #textinfo='none',
        #textinfo='label+value+percent',
        textinfo='text',
        textposition="auto", type = 'pie') %>% layout(title = 'Percentage Effort time', showlegend=T,
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

A newer method for if you'd like to avoid creating a text template to 'overwrite' the values shown in the default way (works in python):

```
fig.update_traces(
        textposition="outside",
        texttemplate="%{label} (%{percent:.1%f})",
        ...
```

Th2 ':.1%f' portion will round values to 1 decimal place, while ':.0%f' will give values rounded to whole numbers

Answer (score 1):

within the brackets of plot_ly(), add:

```
texttemplate='%{percent:.2p}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This would give you 2 digits rounded percentage, with value shown multiply by 100 and suffix with "%":

```
texttemplate = '%{text:.2p}'
```

Here is the complete reference of [d3-format's syntax](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Formatting.md#d3_forma) I found in the documentation.